# How to test WebAPI Controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I have an webAPI application that has a Repository layer, DTO service layer, and WebAPI layer.  WebAPI calls DTO calls Repository.

My repository begins like this:

```
public class RepositoryService : IRepositoryService
    {
        private readonly DbContext _db;

        public RepositoryService(string connectionString)
        {
            _db = new DbContext(connectionString);
        }

        public RepositoryService()
        {
            _db = new DbContext();
        }
```

And my DTO Service begins like this:

```
public class DtoService : IDtoService
    {
        private readonly RepositoryService _repository;

        public DtoService(string connectionString)
        {
            _repository = new RepositoryService(connectionString);  
        }

        public DtoService()
        {
            _repository = new RepositoryService();   
        }
```

My DbContext looks like this:

```
public DbContext() : base("name=TestConnection")
        {

        }

public DbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
        {

        }
```

This, so far, has allowed me to optionally define a connection string to use when running the application for tests.

**First question:**  Does this approach seem ok?

Now that I'm up to my WebAPI layer, I don't just have a single controller class.  I have a bunch of different controllers.  I'm thinking about going through and implementing these constructors for each of the controllers, but there's gotta be a better way to do this.  Something tells me this is where dependency injection comes into play, but I'm not sure.

I could do something like this:

1. Create constructors for each controller like I have for my services above
2. In my test, new up an instance of each controller like

   var accountController = new AccountController(connectionStringForTesting)

But I know this is not practical, so...

**Second Question:** What would a practical approach look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in unit tests, then it's good practice to mock up a database, so your tests do not rely on any kind of IO or database. You may want to hide your `DBContext` behind an interface and use any mocking framework ([Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/moq) for instance) to mock requests' callbacks instead of passing connection string.

If you are interested in integration testing, then you'll need only separate database and all your code can remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

To make your classes nicely unit testable it's a good practise to inject all your dependencies, so that you can test each one of the classes in isolation.

Below an attempt on doing it - it won't work out of the box as you'd need to wire up the dependencies in the container of your choice, and the configuration might be different depending on where you are getting it from but I hope you'll get the idea.

```
 public DbContext(IConfig config) : base(config.ConnectionString)
 { 
 }

public interface IConfig
{
   string ConnectionString {get;}
}

public class RepositoryService : IRepositoryService
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public RepositoryService(IDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}

public class DtoService : IDtoService
    {
        private readonly RepositoryService _repository;

        public DtoService(IRepositoryService repository)
        {
        }
}
```

After all this is done you'd use a mocking framework as suggested by Dima - in Rhino.Mocks you'd go something along these lines:

```
var config = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IConfig>();
config.Stub(c => c.ConnectionString).Return("yourConnectionString");

var dbContext = MockRepository<IDbContext>();

var controller = new YourController([mockDependency1], [mockDependency2]);

controller.[YourMethod]();
_dbContext.AssertWasCalled(dc => dc.[theMEthodYouExpectToHaveBeenCalled])
```